# How to run Pygame in Mac background

Tags: python, macos, input, background, pygame

Im wondering how to provide keyboard input to a running python/pygame program that is in my Mac's background.

Have moved this question to:
[How to test if global key is pressed on Mac using PyObjC and Python.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866920/how-to-test-if-global-key-is-pressed-on-mac-using-pyobjc-and-python)
And no longer using Pygame.

Comment: Why, exactly, are you A) running a game in the background and B) wanting to send input to it?

Comment: Its not a game, I just use pygame for its simple and easy to use input/output features. I want to send input to it while its in the background because I want to use other apps while its running.

Answer (score 0):

I think I interpret this question as: "I need to automate keyboard input". If so, [dogtail](https://fedorahosted.org/dogtail/)
is a good idea. However, since your program is going to be in the background, this may complicate matters, do you have the source to the game you're trying to pass input to?

Comment: I do have the code, however, Im wondering about how to run it in the background, not how to "...automate keyboard input". It already works when its in the foreground I just want it to also receive the keyboard input when its in the background. Its not a game by the way I just use pygame for its simple and easy to use I/O.